# Overloading templated functions

Tags: c++, overloading

I have a doubt about if that approach is possible, lets say you want two ways of calling a function at same time, one is returning an object and the other return by reference in parameter:

```cpp
// ...  
template <class T> void func(Foo<T>& f, const T n) 
{ 
    f.a = Something(f.a + n); 
    f.b = Something(f.b + n); 
}

template <class T> Foo<T> func(const Foo<T>& f, const T n) 
{ 
    return Foo<T>( Something(f.a + n), Something(f.b + n) ); 
}
// ...


// main
Foo<int> foo(1, 1);

func(foo, 2);
Foo<int> foo2 = func(foo, 2);
```

The const word in first parameter affect the signature of method?

Comment: I don't think you can do it taht way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a reference to `const` is a separate type to a reference to non-`const`, so the two functions with these arguments are separate overloads.

However, this will not work:

```
Foo<int> foo2 = func(foo, 2);
```

Since `foo` is not `const`, this will select the non-`const` overload, which has no return value; so the assignment will fail. You would need to explicitly choose the `const` version:

```
Foo<int> foo2 = func(static_cast<const Foo<T>&>(foo), 2);
```

Comment: Why not use `const_cast` instead?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Because `const_cast` is a more dangerous cast than is needed; in this case, it could remove a `volatile` qualifier. (Although `static_cast` could perform an unsafe type conversion; unfortunately, there's no explicit cast that only allows standard conversions).

Answer (score 5):

Yes it does. `const` affects the signature, the return type does not.

#### 1.3.11 signature

> the information about a function that participates in overload
>   resolution (13.3): its parameter-type-list (8.3.5) and, if the
>   function is a class member, the cv-qualifiers (if any) on the function
>   itself and the class in which the member function is declared. [...]

`const` is part of hte parameter-type-list, so it does determine an overload.